# Using this.props.location.pathname is good practice or not

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

using this way is good or bad:
is there any other way to implement it

```
class ProjectContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    const { location } = this.props
    let { actions, projectData } = this.props;
    return (
      <div style={{height: "auto",overflow: "auto"}}>
        {location.pathname === project?
        <Project/>
        :
        location.pathname === projectForm&&
          <Projectform/>}
      </div>
      //the above code is working but i wanna know is good way to use and do i can do it in any other way
    );
  }
```

Comment: Have a look at react-router: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router

Comment: This may be better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

That will be safe if you used withRouter with that component so that will always add location object in your component props.

first you need to import this.
import { withRouter } from 'react-roter-dom';

and when you export this function use

export withRouter(ProjectContainer);

or

export default withRouter(ProjectContainer);